# calculate auc roc for no binary classifiers (scikit-learn)

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to calculate auc roc score for no binary classifiers, I don't seem to find an example in scikit-learn. Any idea how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiclass auc roc can be achieved by either calculating the curve for every class independently or aggregating the values between the classes.

You can find more information [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html), but below I also attach the code for plotting the various curves (code came from the link attached):

```
# Compute macro-average ROC curve and ROC area

# First aggregate all false positive rates
all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

# Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes

fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

# Plot all ROC curves
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
     label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
           ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
     color='deeppink', linestyle=':', linewidth=4)

plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
     label='macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
           ''.format(roc_auc["macro"]),
     color='navy', linestyle=':', linewidth=4)

colors = cycle(['aqua', 'darkorange', 'cornflowerblue'])
for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
         label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
         ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Some extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```